# Saving in any frame just churns

Tags: database

Every time I save in a frame I get the following error.

> Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame\n\n  thrown in /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107

I am using Drupal 7.43 and CiviCRM 4.6.14. An upgrade to 4.6.16 failed and I have restored to backup and am now unable to save anything that is done inside a frame.

Comment: Have you cleared/rebuilt caches?

Comment: Hi Laryn - Many thanks for your reply. I had refresshed the cache without success but it turned out that there was one log table which had 'crash status' and when I used phpmyadmin to repair all tables the issue was resolved.